# Regular neighbourhoods of non-orintable surfaces in $S^4$

Tags: geometric-topology, low-dimensional-topology

Suppose that $F \subset S^4$ is a non-orientable surface. Let $N \subset S^4$ be a regular neighbourhood of $F$. Clearly, the boundary of $N$ is a circle bundle over $F$. Which is its Euler number? My guess is that it is equal to zero, I wish to know a proof...

Comment: It's a bundle whose *fiber* is a circle, but it's not a $U(1)$-bundle, so I don't know what the Euler number means. Thinking of it as an $O(2)$-bundle, I could take its $w_1$, $w_2$, which you can calculate in terms of those of the surface...

Comment: I mean $\partial N$ is a Seifert manifold fibering over $F$ without singular fibers, so it has its associated Euler number (describing completely its topology)

Comment: I do not think there is a well defined Euler number in this situation. You may want to spell out exactly how you are defining this invariant. The definition of Euler number for Seifert bundles requires the bundle to become trivial after deletion of singular fibers (which you do not have) and one point (in case there are no singular fibers). But lack of orientability makes this impossible.

Comment: Check this book https://books.google.hu/books/about/Algorithmic_and_Computer_Methods_for_Thr.html?id=bjcZAQAAIAAJ&redir_esc=y Page 235

Comment: $Homeo^+(S^1)$ retracts on $SO(2)$, so I think that $\partial N$ can be thought as an $U(1)$-bundle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an answer which I am not comfortable assessing the correctness of as I cannot find all the relevant sections of Whitney's paper and I don't understand Massey's.

This apparently a somewhat well-known question of Hassler Whitney. It seems the Euler number can be nonzero. I think the Euler number (with twisted coefficients) here https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.pjm/1102978058 agrees with the Seifert invariant definition. The proof critically uses the famous Atiyah-Singer index theorem.

This apparently unfinished [preprint](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0ahUKEwiImYvt87vKAhXC74MKHVkMAr4QFggvMAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.maths.usyd.edu.au%2Fres%2FGeoTop%2FCri%2Femb-Sei-4.ps&usg=AFQjCNH14g8UpVP8KVmwfeofPG8BT1s1QQ) claims to prove that the Euler numbers from Massey's paper are precisely the ones realized by any embeddings of such Seifert fibred spaces into $S^4$ (without the condition that the embedding comes from the regular neighborhood of a surface). Both sources claim that the Euler numbers realized are $$\{2\chi-4,2\chi,2\chi+4,\dots,4-2\chi\}$$ where $\chi$ is the Euler characteristic of the surface.